# Python - Iterate over 2 lists of a different length in a specific way

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have 2 lists of a different length

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_2 = ['a', 'b']
```

If I'd do:

```
for (i,j) in itertools.zip_longest(list_1, list_2):
print (i,j)
```

The output would be

```
1 a
2 b
3 None
4 None
5 None
```

What I want is to iterate over those 2 lists, but repeat the shorter list when it gets exhausted any amount of times while the longer list still iterates. In this example I'd want output to be

```
1 a
2 b
3 a
4 b
5 a
```

Comment: Can `list_2` be longer than `list_1`? If so, what should be the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an `itertools` for that. You want to `cycle` the second list and do a vanilla `zip` on the first. `cycle` will remember and reemit values from `list_2` and `zip` will stop at the end of `list_1`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list_2 = ['a', 'b']
>>> for i,j in zip(list_1, itertools.cycle(list_2)):
...     print(i, j)
... 
1 a
2 b
3 a
4 b
5 a
```

if you want the result to always be the longer of the two lists (either could cycle), you'd need to choose which one uses `itertools.cycle`. There are a dozen ways to do that, but here's one

```
>>> zipper = zip(list_1, itertools.cycle(list_2)) if len(list_1) >= len(list_2) else zip(itertools.cycle(list_1), list_2)
>>> for i, j in zipper:
...     print(i, j)
... 
1 a
2 b
3 a
4 b
5 a
```

And if you want something that works for iterators in general (they wouldn't know their size in advance), you could make them into a list first.